# Troubleshooting Local Port Forwarding Example

Tags: ssh

Attempts to reproduce a [Local Port Forwarding](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-local-and-remote-ssh-port-forwarding/) example on 16.04 with the command:

```
$ ssh -L 8080:www.slashdot.org:80 localhost
```

returns:

ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

The tutorial sets the expectation: **You will be prompted to enter your user password for the client  machine.**

> Essentially, you are connecting, via SSH, back to your
>   client machine, but creating the necessary SSH tunnel to the
>   destination. After you've successfully authenticated against your
>   local account, open up a browser and point it to
>   http://localhost:8080. Your browser should automatically redirect you
>   to Slashdot.'

Any insight as to why I am not prompted for my Ubuntu credentials at the command line is appreciated.

## UPDATES

```
$ systemctl status ssh.service
```

returns:

```
● ssh.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Do you have an SSH server running on `localhost`? what does `systemctl status ssh.service` say?

Comment: @steeldriver  Thanks for the good question.  Results are posted at the OP tail.

Comment: OK so it looks like it is not running - and possibly not even installed. Make sure you have done so (ex. `sudo apt install openssh-server`)

Comment: @steeldriver  I was under the (incorrectly) under the impression that an ssh server was running out of the box.  Thank you for helping to trouble shoot.  If you post as an answer, I will award credit.

Comment: Thanks - answer added below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use this type of port forwarding, there needs to be an SSH server running on the localhost. The somewhat unspecific error message

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

*may* indicate that there isn't (although it can also indicate a problem with configuration or firewalling).

On current (systemd based) Ubuntu systems, you can check if such a server is running using

```
systemctl status ssh.service
```

If necessary, install the default OpenSSH server using

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

(it should start automatically if the install command succeeds).