# Port Forwarding Example: Test Failure Troubleshooting

Tags: networking, ssh

This is a follow-up question to the example [Troubleshooting Local Port Forwarding Example](https://askubuntu.com/q/1210614/545291)

Attempts to reproduce a [Local Port Forwarding](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-local-and-remote-ssh-port-forwarding/) example on 16.04 with the command:

```
$ ssh -L 8080:www.slashdot.org:80 localhost
```

returns:

```
user@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-173-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
Linux azimuth 4.4.0-173-generic #203-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 15 02:55:01 UTC 2020 x86_64

10 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

New release '18.04.4 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

## Theory / Verification procedure:

> Essentially, you are connecting, via SSH, back to your
>   client machine, but creating the necessary SSH tunnel to the
>   destination. After you've successfully authenticated against your
>   local account, open up a browser and point it to
>   http://localhost:8080. Your browser should automatically redirect you
>   to Slashdot.'

## ERRORS & QUESTIONS

Firefox returns: "Unable to connect" from http://localhost:8080 and https also fails.  I am expecting the slashdot website to be returned.

- What are the test / questions to be asked to begin troubleshooting?
- Are there any BASH tests that can confirm that the tunnel has been mapped to slashdot?
- What are the necessary conditions for the example to work as expected?

Comment: Is it http or https? Try to connect to http only site, like `example.com`. I wouldn't expect you to connect to an https site with this method.

Comment: See also this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426542/how-to-make-ssh-port-fowarding-for-https if you are trying to connect to an https site. Or the http site may be redirecting you to its https version.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Good eye: Both http and https fail to return slashdot

Comment: I would try a simple http site like `example.com` first... And did you read the hints in the link I provided?

Comment: `localhost:8080` returns the same results.  The example calls for http:// to be invoked.   If I can avoid the https complications that would be preferable